# How to swipe fluller Dismissible widget programmatically?

Tags: flutter, swipe, dismissible

I have [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) with [Dismissible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) items.

I can dismiss items manually (by swiping from left to right).

Also I can dismiss items programmatically (like in this [example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html#widgets.AnimatedList.1)), but items disappear without swiping.

How to make list items move from left to right (before they disappear)?